# select query BETWEEN two dates in WindowsForms Application c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I have a problem with the query BETWEEN .I'm trying to select records from a table between two dates, SO, I used the following query :

```
SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(
  "select distinct * from BLC where DATE_BLC between '" + 
   dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "' and'" + 
   dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "'", conx);
```

When I enter the following dates :

From  date 05/02/2016  To date 15/03/2016

It returns the records between (06/02/2016 to 15/03/2016) date but the records that begin with date 05/02/2016 , they are not returned.
and when I choose the date (From 05/02/2016 to 05/02/2016 ) there is no records here.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: your dateTimePicker1 is sending time stamp also to SQL, try to pass only Date

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Have you any idea how  to secure it ?

Comment: parameterized queries. Query parameters also have the nice features of being faster and avoiding issues with single quotes in fields or formatting issues with dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass only `Date` value instead of `DateTime` value

```
SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct * from BLC where DATE_BLC between '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "' and'" + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "'", conx);
```

Comment: @Y.Arsoy you should mark the answer as the correct solution if it solved your problem.

Comment: @tobypls I am new here , I didn't find where should i mark it solved ?

Comment: @Y.Arsoy - there should be a tick mark right below down arrow left to this answer

Comment: @Y.Arsoy http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 8):

It is a better codding practice to use parameters as they will sterilize any inputs for any queries and are generally safer to user. Thus the code would become

```
SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct * from BLC where DATE_BLC between @Date1 and @Date2", conx);
sda1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date1", dateTimePicker1.Value));
sda1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date2", dateTimePicker2.Value));
```